# Error installing rails: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xcode, rvm

I tried everything from others' posts. 
-I'm on Lion
-Installed Xcode 4.6.3 (4H1503)
-Brew up to date and ready to brew
-Installed rvm with ruby 2.0.0
-Installed command line tools - gcc42-4.2.1-
- tried 'sudo ln -s llvm-gcc-4.2 gcc-4.2'

And still get this error below. Please help!!

---

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
/junetic.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

/junetic.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby: invalid option -H  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)

Gem files will remain installed in /junetic.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /junetic.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out

Comment: what is in the `/junetic.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/atomic-1.1.10/ext/gem_make.out`

Comment: I run to a similar question on centos, ruby-2.0.0-p247, looking for help

Comment: @mpapis, it should be `/junetic.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb`. the failed command

Comment: same thing in gem_make.out-/junetic.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/junetic.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby: invalid option -H  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)